# Run HttpContext.Cache.Remove when close browser window (asp.net c # vs 2012)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, caching, httpcontext

I have the following problem, I am working on a project with vb.net visual studio 2012 and I manage the sessions by HttpContext.Cache, to eliminate the session stored in the cache, add a button that executes the cleaning process, but I would like to add it to same way when closing the browser tab or directly closing the entire browser (Chrome, Safari, Opera, Internet Explorer).

for register user in session

```
Public Sub registrarSesion(ByVal contexto As HttpContext, ByVal nombreusuario As String)
    Dim TimeOut As TimeSpan = New TimeSpan(0, 0, contexto.Session.Timeout, 0, 0)
    nombreusuario = nombreusuario.Trim()
    If contexto.Cache(nombreusuario) Is Nothing Then contexto.Cache.Insert(nombreusuario, contexto.Session.SessionID, Nothing, DateTime.MaxValue, TimeOut, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, Nothing)
    contexto.Session("nombreusuario") = nombreusuario
End Sub
```

for delete user in session

```
   Public Sub EliminarRegistro(ByVal contexto As HttpContext)
    If contexto.Session("nombreusuario") IsNot Nothing Then contexto.Cache.Remove(contexto.Session("nombreusuario").ToString())
End Sub
```

this code is call from exit button

```
Protected Sub CerrarSesion_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles CerrarSesion.Click
    LiberarSesion()
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
    Session.Abandon()
    Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx", False)
    ClosePag(Me.Page)        
End Sub
```

and the method LiberarSesion()

```
 Public Shared Sub LiberarSesion()
    Dim clase As ValidaSesion = New ValidaSesion()
    clase.EliminarRegistro(HttpContext.Current)
End Sub
```

From already thank you very much :)

Comment: The only way this could work is to use the [onbeforeunload event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onbeforeunload.asp) in JavaScript to send an AJAX request back to your server when the tab/browser closes and have a handler/page/action method abandon the session. This would inadvertently wipe out the session for any tabs/browsers that are still open, as there is no way to tell when the browser is really done with the application.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, but I already try this method and it does not detect it, apply a webmetod in conjunction with ajax and this does not respond when closing the browser tab, but the funny thing is that only in this case it does not respond, if it is called in the onclick event of a button if it responds, do you know what it might be?